# error on adding changeListener on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jtextfield, documentlistener

here my situation:

```
textField1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            textField1StateChanged(e);
        }
    });
```

the error said addChangeListener is undefined for the type JTextField.
is there any thing else to import? (i'm a newbie in java)
thanks

Answer (score 2):

you might want to try this:

```
// Listen for changes in the text
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      //your code
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
  }
});
```

Comment: More info can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html

Answer (score 2):

> is there any thing else to import?

This is not about imports, [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) has methods available.  That is not one of them.

See [Listeners Supported by Swing Components: Other Listeners that Swing Components Support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html#many) for details in a table.

Comment: if you are using netbeans, it will suggest all needed imports for you. I always use it this way so I barely know what to import any more :D

Answer (score 1):

Thats because there is no such method in JTextField. What you have to do instead is make your class implement ChangeListener, and implement the `stateChanged()` method. Here you will get the component that triggered the event from the ChangeEvent passed in, and act accordingly. Here is an example from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html):

```
class YourClass implements ChangeListener {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JTextField) {
           JTextField source = (JTextField)e.getSource();
           if(!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
             // check if this is the component you want and respond to the event 
           }
        }    
    }
}
```